# Add Expires headers for specific files in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, header, mod-expires

I'm trying to add browser caching rules to my `.htaccess` file, with different expiry rules for files in a certain directory. The general rules are being applied OK but the directory specific rules are not.

This is the section in my `.htaccess` file (the `FilesMatch` rule is to target the directory):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

  # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 day"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  <FilesMatch "^(assets/foundation/5.5.3)$">
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 day"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 day"
</IfModule>
```

These are the files I'm trying to target:

```
https://cm.anyware.co.nz/assets/foundation/5.5.3/css/normalize.css
https://cm.anyware.co.nz/assets/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css
https://cm.anyware.co.nz/assets/foundation/5.5.3/js/vendor/modernizr.js
https://cm.anyware.co.nz/assets/foundation/5.5.3/js/vendor/jquery.js
https://cm.anyware.co.nz/assets/foundation/5.5.3/js/foundation.min.js
https://cm.anyware.co.nz/assets/foundation/5.5.3/js/foundation.dropdown.js
https://cm.anyware.co.nz/assets/foundation/5.5.3/js/foundation.topbar.js
```

GTMetrix says these static components do not have a far-future expiration date.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <FilesMatch "^(assets/foundation/5.5.3)$">
> ```

The `<FilesMatch>` (and `<Files>`) directive matches against the filename  only, eg, `normalize.css`, `foundation.min.css`, etc. which is not what you require.

The easiest way to target this specific directory only is to create another `.htaccess` file in this directory with the necessary overrides.

Alternatively, you can use an Apache Expression on Apache 2.4+ and check against the `REQUEST_URI`, although this isn't necessarily the same as the directory (depending on your system).

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/assets/foundation/5\.5\.3/#">
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</If>
```